# How to subtract hours from a (datetime) textfield and display results in a 2nd textfield

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

I have a datetime textfield (textfield 1) where the user enters the datetime in Y-m-d H:i:s format. I want to subtract 8 hours from the value entered in textfield 1 and display the results in a 2nd textfield (textfield 2)

How can this be done?

Comment: This is a matter of simple mathematics my friend

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: With or without refreshing the page. The solution will depend greatly on the answer.

Comment: This is not a matter of "simple mathematics," it's date code. You don't roll your own date/time math code unless you really love creating bugs already solved somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
var datetime=window.document.getElementById("field1").value; //store date string
datetime=new Date(datetime.replace(" ","T")+"Z");
datetime.setHours(-8);
datetime=datetime.toISOString().replace("T"," ").split(".")[0];
window.document.getElementById("field2").value=datetime;
```